# pyaudio FATAL error on ARM environment

Tags: arm, pyaudio

I have encountered the pyaudio problem on arm platform.

Is there any workaround?

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 18:31:26)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyaudio
>>> pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:618:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:961:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
FATAL: cannot locate cpu MHz in /proc/cpuinfo
```

Answer (score 0):

Just workaround.
I patched to jackd2 on ARM Ubuntu 14.04 according to the below link,

> https://gist.github.com/rogerallen/0346a1812deda2a380da

and modified /etc/ld.so.conf:

> /usr/local/lib
>   include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf

and

> $ sudo ldconfig